# Is it possible to "try out" guns?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I am just starting out and it's expensive to buy guns just to find out that I dislike them. Where can I test weapons in *Call of Duty: Black Ops*?

Comment: There is no such thing as best gun in the Modern Warfare series. Please refine your question if you need a specific information.

Comment: Perhaps it should be rephrased to ask how to find which gun suits you best without having to purchase them all in multiplayer?

Comment: @Bora - Obviously you have not been playing Call of Duty for that long.  There is always a gun that out performs all other guns in the series.  For example, UMP45 in MW2 was pretty powerful.  So was the MP40 in World at War.

Comment: fyi: I am now Prestige 2 in BlackOps and played up to Prestige 4 in MW2. I could own with every gun, from AT4 and down to the knife. There is no best gun if you know how to use them. "Playstyle" or "preferences", those are different subjects.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be closed? It's argumentative and subjective.

Comment: @Carlo it was on purposely made subjective. I answered my own question though basically saying the question is subjective. Read both my question and answer. I couldn't think of any other way of telling people about my amazing process of trying out guns :)

Comment: @Carlo I also changed the title to not be so plainly subjective.

Comment: This question has been attracting a number of answers directed at the original subjective title "What guns are the best", both before and after the edit to the current rendition. To prevent these off-topic answers from further accumulating and to keep this question on track, all such off-topic answers are being deleted, including the ones which may have been appropriate when initially provided (note that none had earned any reputation, so no losses incurred!). In the future, we hopefully won't run into many more incidents of question revisions largely invalidating answers...

Comment: @Grace yea, that's my fault. I shouldn't have originally started it out with such a subjective sounding title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No one can say what is the best gun for someone else. It just takes practice with each gun and such. But there is a way to try out guns without having to spend your precious COD points.

Just enter combat training. Make the difficulty "recruit" and setup a game of team deathmatch and 9 enemies against just you. This will give you tons of XP and COD points in combat training. It took me about 2 hours to get to level 25 with this. Once you unlock the gun and have the COD points, just buy it from combat training. Use it and figure out if you like it, then go back to the real game and buy it if you wish. I did this after prestiging once and I regret it. I would've got to first prestige much faster if I had known what guns would work for me and what wouldn't. (same goes for perks and equipment and such)

Answer (score 1):

You could play several rounds of the [Sharpshooter Wager Match mode](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Sharpshooter) and make a note of any weapons you like.

If you play in low buy in rounds it shouldn't cost you very much at all and if you do well you may come out better off.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just run around playing with the default guns for a few days, then go into your stats and see what guns kill you the most. Chances are people are a little more efficient with those guns, or they're just popular, but they're probably popular for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

To find what guns suit you, go onto split-screen. From there all weapons, camos - anything unlockable - is usable. These, however, don't carry over to the multiplayer. You won't really be able to test them out properly unless you have another person with you, but you'll be able to check out if you want to spend money on the camos and stuff, as well as get a feel for the weapon (e.g recoil).

Answer (score 1):

Another great way to 'try out' guns is to set a class that has scavenger, what ever tier 2 and 3 perks you like, and pick up guns from people you kill.  This way you can try out the guns in real combat, though it might take you a bit longer to do so.

Comment: I do this anyway when I prestige and don't have my favorite guns :P

Answer (score 0):

go to system link match. create game. and all the options are there

Comment: This doesn't let you try against enemy players, for instance to see how well the range, accuracy, and damage are.